# Evaluating select projection

Tags: c#, expression, predicate

Is it possible to evaluate a select projection at some point to get a list of which properties are being selected?

For example, if I have the following class:

```
public class Example()
{
    public string Aaa { get; set; }

    public int Bbb { get; set; }

    public string Ccc { get; set; }
}
```

and the following select projection:

```
Expression<Func<Example, Example>> select = x => new Example { Aaa= x.Aaa, Ccc = x.Ccc };
```

Would it be possible to interpret the select projection to get a result along the lines of `var result = new List<string> { "Aaa", "Ccc" };`?

Comment: Are you saying you want to walk the lambda's parse tree and retrieve a list of the names of all the properties its code references? If so, yes, that can be done.

Comment: A predicate is a function that produces a boolean value.  That's a projection (something that transforms a value into another type of value).

Comment: @EdPlunkett That sounds about right. How would I go about doing so? I have tried to evaluate the Bindings[] at runtime, however the values are protected and cannot be accessed outside of the watch/quick watch.

Comment: @MrThursday Did any answer solved it for you? If so, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do something like this is using an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is an example:

```
public class MyMemberExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property // is a property
            && node.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter // is from a parameter expression
            && Members.All(s => s != node.Member.Name)) // avoids duplicates
        {
            Members.Add(node.Member.Name);
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    public List<string> Members { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
// Complex expressions work too!
Example outsideExample = new Example();
Expression<Func<Example, Example>> expression = x => new Example(
    x.Aaa + outsideExample.Bbb,
    x.Ccc + x.Aaa.Length);

var myVisitor = new MemberExpressionVisitor();
myVisitor.Visit(expression);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", myVisitor.Members)); // This should print out "Aaa, Ccc"
```

You can visit [How to: Implement an Expression Tree Visitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(v=vs.90).aspx) to learn more on how to implement one.

Comment: Note that not all members are properties.

Answer (score -2):

To find all of the property expressions within that expression you can use an `ExpressionVisitor` to inspect all of the `Expression` instances within a given expression and see which are property accesses, and what property is being accessed:

```
internal class PropertySearchVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private List<MemberInfo> properties = new List<MemberInfo>();
    public IEnumerable<MemberInfo> Properties => properties;
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node?.Member?.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
            properties.Add(node.Member);
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

Once you have that you can write a method to visit a given expression and return the properties (or property names) of that expression:

```
public static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetProperties(this Expression expression)
{
    var visitor = new PropertySearchVisitor();
    visitor.Visit(expression);
    return visitor.Properties;
}
public static IEnumerable<string> GetPropertyNames(this Expression expression)
{
    var visitor = new PropertySearchVisitor();
    visitor.Visit(expression);
    return visitor.Properties.Select(property => property.Name);
}
```